# How can I define and use a variable in XAML to define a color?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a number of elements in my XAML which define **Foreground="#555"** to be the color of faded text in a readonly textbox.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SingularModelClassFileTitle}" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SingularModelClassFileName}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         Foreground="#555"
         Width="500"/>
<TextBox 
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
 AcceptsReturn="True"                  
 Width="500" 
 Height="100" 
 IsReadOnly="True" 
 Foreground="#555"
 Text="{Binding SingularModelClassContent}"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Margin="0 0 0 20"/>
```

How can I **put this value in a XAML variable** and reference in each attribute it so that I only have to change it in one place?

I'm thinking you can do **something like this**:

```
<sys:String x:Key="ReadOnlyTextColor">#555</sys:String>

...

    <TextBox Foreground="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextColor}"/>
```

And what would be the property `xmlns:sys=...` reference for this?

Comment: You ask good questions, Edward. While learning WPF you name pops up time and again ;-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try defining your color as a [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ReadOnlyTextBrush" Color="#555555" />
```

...

```
<TextBox Foreground="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextColor}" />
```

Comment: Matt, is the reason `Color` can't be used directly as a `StaticResource` because it's a value type, not a reference type?

Comment: @MattDavis `Color` cannot be used because the Foreground property of TextBox is of type `Brush`. You can create a `Color` and reference that as `StaticResource` within the `SolidColorBrush`.

Answer (score 55):

Sometimes you may need to define colors rather than brushes : (one case you would want this is to be able to define Gradients with color parameters) 
In that case you could just define them like this:

```
 <Color x:Key="ButtonColor1">Blue</Color>
 <Color x:Key="ButtonColor1">#AABBCC</Color>
 <Color x:Key="ButtonColor1" A="0" R="124" G="111" B="44"/>
```

Comment: Sadly, the last option throws "Failed to create a 'System.Byte' from the text '00'." on Windows Phone. The second one worked like a charm, cheers!

Comment: And then to reference the color use `{StaticResource Blue}`

Comment: @StephenHosking, no, to reference the color use `{StaticResource ButtonColor1}`

Comment: The last one should be `A="0"`. You're working with bytes here, not string representations of hex digits.