# Defining a color in App.xaml and using as a static resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

EDIT: Looks like this was related to the way I declared the color - using  hex value seems to bring it through fine.

EDIT: This about referencing **from** the App.xaml file. The color itself works fine if declared as a local resource.

I've created a colour:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TestBlue">
    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
        <Color R="0" G="86" B="45"/>
    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
</SolidColorBrush>
```

and placed it in a ResourceDictionary. I've then referenced it in a MergedDictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="Colours.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="View\Item\ItemResource.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

When I apply it to the background of a Button as a StaticResource it doesn't apply:

```
Background="{StaticResource TestBlue}"
```

When I Snoop the control it declares the Background as some other value:
[image: Background]

It also doesn't work if I make it an entry in the  itself (like the ViewModelLocator). It does work if I place it in the Window.Resources. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I define and use a variable in XAML to define a color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037477/how-can-i-define-and-use-a-variable-in-xaml-to-define-a-color)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide value for Alpha (transparency) channel, because Color is structure and it's default value for that value is zero (transparent).

```
<Color A="255" R="0" G="86" B="45"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use it as a StaticResource, you must include your ResourceDictionnary where you want to use your Resource. Otherwise, you'll have to use it as a DynamicResource.

So if your button is in its own xaml file, you'll have to include your ResourceDictionnary in the button's xaml file, as you did in App.xaml.