# How do I set a color as a Static Resource to be used throughout an application?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have buttons throughout my application like this:

```
<Button Content="Click me" Background="#7AC040" />
```

And I've even set up some static resources to style table column headers:

```
<Style x:Key="TableHeadersStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7AC040" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Now as you can see, I've been hardcoding the values of what I want the colors of various components to be.  However, now that the application is growing large, I'd like to "extract" those colors into a static resource "variable" of some sort that I can put in place of those hex values. Is there a way for me to do so?

Maybe something like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="CompanyColor">#NewColorHEX</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

... 

<Button Content="Click me" Background="{StaticResource CompanyColor}" />

....

<Style x:Key="TableHeadersStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CompanyColor}" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work but is there a way for me to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037495/5228202 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the resource as a `Brush`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CompanyBrush" Color="#7AC040" />
```

You can then use it to set any `Brush` property:

```
<Button Content="Click me" Background="{StaticResource CompanyColor}" />
```

You cannot set the `Background` property to a `Color` value - only to a `Brush`.

Comment: I am afraid it is duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037495/5228202